# Is it possible to get by type name of std::tuple which are duplicated?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using Name = std::string;
using NodeType = int;
using ElementType = int;

std::tuple<Name, NodeType, ElementType> myTuple("hi", 12, 42);

cout<<std::get<NodeType>(myTuple)<<endl;
```

This generates compile error.

I can use `std::get<1>(myTuple)` but it's not easy to read as `std::get<NodeType>(myTuple)`, is there any way to get value by type in this case?

Comment: Seems like you might be better off with just a named class to avoid the headache.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes. The only problem is this tuple is defined in other file that I can't change...

Comment: Why exactly would you want that?

Comment: You could maybe make some dummy structs called `Name`, `NodeType` and `ElementType` in some other namespace and write a non-member `get` function which can use them? Bit horrible though.

Comment: @TartanLlama Boost has [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) to save you some typing on that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum {NodeTypeIdX=1, ElementTypeIdx=2};

std::get<NodeTypeIdx>(myTuple);
```

This works and is self documenting.

The `std::get<Type>` syntax does not support `std::get<Type, which_one>` or anything similar.  It only works when the type is unique.  As you have no control over the tuple's definition, there is nothing (defined) you can do to make the `std::get<Type>` option work.

On the other hand, who cares if the keyword you are using is a type or an enum constant?  The important part is that it has a self-documenting name.

Comment: I used a const int for it but I believe enum is the same.

Answer (score 8):

`NodeType` and `ElementType` are the same type, namely `int`. `typedef` and `using` do not create a new type, only names.

So no, you cannot get either of the last entries by type because their type is not unique in the tuple.

Comment: We've had proposals for strong/opaque typedefs for many years and none of them have made it into the standard yet. This answer is just another proof that we definitely need them standardized

Comment: Here's a "workaround" to strong typedefs: `enum class NodeType : int{};` and `enum class ElementType : int{};`.

Answer (score 1):

A type is the same regardless of how you name it - `int`, `ElementType`, and `NodeType` are equivalent and there is no way to tell them apart.

I would write accessor functions and use those:

```
using Something = std::tuple<Name, NodeType, ElementType>;

NodeType& nodeType(Something& tp)
{
    return std::get<1>(tp);
}

NodeType nodeType(const Something& tp)
{
    return std::get<1>(tp);
}

ElementType& elementType(Something& tp)
{
    return std::get<2>(tp);
}

ElementType elementType(const Something& tp)
{
    return std::get<2>(tp);
}
// ...

cout << nodeType(myTuple) << endl;
elementType(myTuple) = some_type;
```

Comment: You should return references (and probably takes `tp` as a non-const reference, or provide overload) in order to mimic `std::get`. Or maybe use a templated version with forwarding reference to avoid code duplication ;)

Comment: @Holt Yep, I should. (But I'm too unfamiliar with forwarding references to attempt that one.)

Comment: Use forwarding reference, e.g. `template <typename Tuple> auto nodeType_ (Tuple &&t) { return std::get<1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)); }`, this will save you a lot of writing (in any case you should return `const` reference instead of value in the `const` version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Name`, `NodeType`, `ElementType` are **different** types (tags could help probably):

```
template <class T>
struct Names;

template <> struct Names<Name> { static constexpr int i = 0; };
template <> struct Names<NodeType> { static constexpr int i = 1; };
template <> struct Names<ElementType> { static constexpr int i = 2; };
```

You can short it a bit with a helper function:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto index() -> int
{
    return Names<T>::index;
}
```

So you get:

```
cout<<  std::get< index<NodeType>() >(myTuple) <<  endl;
```

I'll give you it's not the best.

Comment: If the types were unique, one could just do what OP does directly as of C++14.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in other answers, `std::get<int>(tuple)` will not work if `tuple` contains more than one single `int`, so it will not work for you.

However, you can make your own `get<>()` which does what you want. The following code defines a template function `my_get<Et,P>(tuple)` that will return a reference to the `(P+1)th` element of type `Et` of `tuple`.

```
template<typename Et, size_t P, typename Ct, size_t N, typename Et2>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Et,Et2>::value && (P == 0), Et&>::type
    my_get(Ct& c, Et2& e)   { return std::get<N>(c); }

template<typename Et, size_t P, typename Ct, size_t N, typename Et2>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Et,Et2>::value && (P > 0), Et&>::type
    my_get(Ct& c, Et2& e)   { return my_get<Et,P-1,Ct,N+1>(c); }

template<typename Et, size_t P, typename Ct, size_t N, typename Et2>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Et,Et2>::value, Et&>::type
    my_get(Ct& c, Et2& e)   { return my_get<Et, P, Ct, N+1>(c, std::get<N+1>(c)); }

template<typename Et, size_t P, typename Ct, size_t N>
Et& my_get(Ct& c)   { return my_get<Et, P, Ct, N>(c, std::get<N>(c)); }

template<typename Et, size_t P, typename Ct>
Et& my_get(Ct& c)   { return my_get<Et, P, Ct, 0>(c); }
```

usage:

```
void tptest()
{
    std::tuple<double,int,double,int> mytuple(1.0,2, 3.0, 4);
    std::cout << "my_get<double,0>(mytuple) = " << my_get<double,0>(mytuple) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my_get<int,0>(mytuple)    = " << my_get<int,0>(mytuple) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my_get<double,1>(mytuple) = " << my_get<double,1>(mytuple) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my_get<int,1>(mytuple)    = " << my_get<int,1>(mytuple) << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
my_get<double,0>(mytuple) = 1
my_get<int,0>(mytuple)    = 2
my_get<double,1>(mytuple) = 3
my_get<int,1>(mytuple)    = 4
```